# Get the boolean array column in PySpark dataframe indicating whether the existing two array column have the same element or not

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe having two array columns as seen below:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| [1, 2, 3] | [1, 4, 3] |
| [5, 4, 3] | [5] |

I want the result to be like this:

| col3 |
| --- |
| [1, 0, 1] |
| [1, 0, 0] |

Also, number of items in col1 is always fixed and greater than or equal to number of items in col2.

I know we can do it using udf. But I am looking for an optimised way of doing it using PySpark SQL functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Higher order function [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html#pyspark.sql.functions.transform) can do it. For every element in array of col1, you check if it is contained in the array of col2.

- If you need array of int:

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  df = spark.createDataFrame(
      [([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3]),
       ([5, 4, 3], [5])],
      ['col1', 'col2'])

  df = df.select(
      F.transform('col1', lambda x: F.array_contains('col2', x).cast('int')).alias('col3')
  )
  df.show()
  # +---------+
  # |     col3|
  # +---------+
  # |[1, 0, 1]|
  # |[1, 0, 0]|
  # +---------+
  ```
- If you need array of boolean:

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  df = spark.createDataFrame(
      [([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3]),
       ([5, 4, 3], [5])],
      ['col1', 'col2'])

  df = df.select(
      F.transform('col1', lambda x: F.array_contains('col2', x)).alias('col3')
  )
  df.show()
  # +--------------------+
  # |                col3|
  # +--------------------+
  # | [true, false, true]|
  # |[true, false, false]|
  # +--------------------+
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you are a fun of expressions;

```
df.selectExpr('*',"transform(transform(col1, x-> array_contains(col2,x)),y->cast(y as integer)) as col3").show()

+---------+---------+---------+
|     col1|     col2|     col3|
+---------+---------+---------+
|[1, 2, 3]|[1, 4, 3]|[1, 0, 1]|
|[5, 4, 3]|      [5]|[1, 0, 0]|
+---------+---------+---------+
```